# How to find out the default init system of my raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, script, init.d

I want to write a script to enable my program on boot automatically. This can be done using SysV Init, Upstart or `systemd`. However, I am not able to figure out which init system my Raspbian uses.

Another doubt I have is that, suppose the default init system is upstart, then will a script written and enabled with `systemd` work? To rephrase, do we need to write init script in the default init system to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

Raspian is basically Debian.

[Debian until and including Wheezy/7 used SysV, since Jessie/8 systemd](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch03.en.html#_stage_4_the_normal_debian_system).

Upstart is not relevant anymore, since even RHEL and Ubuntu (the Upstart developers) have moved to systemd.

systemd is very different from sysv. However, there is a [compatibility layer](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/debugging-systemd-sysv-init-compat) in systemd that will transparently create units for [properly annotated sysv init scripts](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) on the fly. If you plan to distribute your init script to other raspian users, a well-tested sysv init script will also work in systemd. While systemd is pretty complex, creating services is actually [surprisingly  simple](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/getting-started-with-systemd.html).

As for the init system on **your** machine, `stat /sbin/init` should give you a good indication on Debian. For general initsystem detection, this [Unix&Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196166/how-to-find-out-if-a-system-uses-sysv-upstart-or-systemd-initsystem) has excellent answers.
u

Comment: The question link to on U&LSE is marked as a duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) one! Also - Debian (and thus Raspbian) do provide a working choice for init systems on both Wheezy and Jessie versions - those indications are the defaults but the opposite (SysV `init` vs. `systemd`) can be selected - all my machines (PCs & RPis) use SysV `init` even though some are using Jessie...! 8-) {For the record do not try to install `upstart` into an `init` using Jessie system *directly* - that breaks very badly... 8-( }

Comment: sudo stat /sbin/init
  File: ‘/sbin/init’
  Size: 284844     Blocks: 560        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: b307h/45831d Inode: 669590      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-02-17 22:15:59.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2014-12-09 15:36:55.000000000 +0300
Change: 2016-02-17 22:16:07.991854912 +0300
 Birth: -

This is the output. I cannot figure out the init system from this.

Comment: I was able to find out using answers here.http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell